# Using buses to travel from La Thuile to Aosta in place of defunct rail service

Tags: buses, italy, alps

Would skiing travelers be able to return from La Thuile to Pré Saint Didier and board a bus to continue down the valley to Aosta directly? Where is the bus terminal in Pré Saint Didier? Or, does SAVDA's route take you back to Courmayeur to have catch a another bus to Aosta ?

Comment: I appreciate that information and have a La Thuile Ski Shuttle Bus schedule to study . . . it returns to Pré Saint Didier and other buses connect to Courmayeur. It is unfortunate about the loss of train service to that end of the valley.

Comment: I just want to clarify what your asking, are you looking for public transport options (which you could take skis on) from La Thuile to Aosta?

Comment: in [this pdf](http://www.sadem.it/media/750171/000160.pdf) you can find the routes of the bus. Let me know if you need help understanding the structure of the file Lol

Comment: To clariify: Traveling down from skiing at La Thuile, without skis (renting them there) and want to know if there is a bus service to bring you to Pré Saint Didier. Will this bus drop us off where we can then catch the bus to Aosta. Or, will we need to return to Courmayeur's bus plaza to catch the bus that goes to Aosta? Thanks in advance, DJ

Comment: The PDF of the SAVDA bus schedule from La Thuile to Aosta is very helpful and I owe my thanks to Hatef! ;-)

Comment: Did you end up traveling on that bus?

Comment: Thanks for asking, JonathanReez —The extra ski days in La Thuile became too complicated with the bus portion added in. The low snow conditions also contributed to making the decision to finish the ski holiday at Verbier and head over to Lyon, France for a few days exploring that region.

Answer (score 4):

[The Linea 160 SAVDA/SADEM bus goes from Courmayeur to Torino Porta Nuova F.S. and back.](http://www.sadem.it/media/750171/000160.pdf) Its intermediate stops include La Thuile, Pré-Saint-Didier, and Aosta, which are covered by one same bus. This means that you do not have to change at any point during this journey. However, if you wish to continue further than Aosta you will probably have to change bus.

[Alternatively, the SAVDA/SADEM Linea 207 bus also goes from La Thuile to Aosta.,](http://www.savda.it/it/58/valle-d-aosta-torino/) via Pré-Saint-Didier.

For more up-to-date information on the SAVDA/SADEM buses see [their timetable page](http://www.savda.it/it/orari.php).