# Where does the La Thuile to Aosta bus depart from and arrive?

Tags: buses, italy

I have [a PDF](http://www.sadem.it/media/750171/000160.pdf) shared by [Hatef](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85076/using-buses-to-travel-from-la-thuile-to-aosta-in-place-of-defunct-rail-service#comment199220_85076) (many thanks!) that lists a morning bus from La Thuile to Aosta. But the actual bus stop locations (boarding and arrival) are  not indicated.

Does anyone know these locations?

I am intending to arrive at or near the Trenitalia station in Aosta to continue by train to Ivrea and Torino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad to help! In [this](http://www.savda.it/public/linee/allegati/443_it.pdf) PDF you can find some of the stops with their names. Please note this is an older one. Some of those information might not be valid anymore. But anyway, in the second column you can find the boarding points - I also provide you some details regarding the abbrev. you find in this file:

*SS 26* stands for: *Strada Statale 26 della Valle d'Aosta* (so wherever you see this I guess you should stand in the highway waiting for the passing bus?)

*FS* in Italy generally stands for: *train station (ferrovie dello stato)*

---

I also suggest you to install the app of the company. You can find it [here](http://savda.it/it/85/nuova-app-savdabus/). I did a sample search of your route and the result seems to be clear enough - furthermore you can directly buy the ticket from there.

As you can see in the screenshot first you should go to *Bivio F.S* in the Pre Saint Didier - and then from there (actually from *SS 26*) take another bus to Aosta - in the attached PDF I see the difference between these two (Bivio F.S && SS26) is 2 minutes by bus so I'd say it's a 5 minutes walk.

[image: SAVDA APP]

---

Comment: Very helpful +1

Comment: Thanks to Hatef! I now know route/options/times for AVDA bus system. From "Street View" on Google Earth I "walked" the route — found bus stop locations in Pre' St Didier where the La Thuile bus arrives, and 300 m down the street to the S.S. 26 bus, the stop shelter and marked lane on the east side of the roadway at the triangular access road reached via a pedestrian underpass. Also, the bus plaza in Aosta (D-B) is a block-long open air with covered facility just across the street and east of the Aosta train station.

Comment: I now "Know" and I should have thanked Hatef, perhaps? THANKS TO ALL!